# stop / start service or close the sql server process / service on a remote computer

Tags: c#, process, windows-services, remote-access

I am trying to shutdown and start the sql server on a remote computer (on the same network), i have used this code

```
ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
options.Username = userName;
options.Password = password;

ManagementScope scope = 
         new ManagementScope(
                       string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\cimv2", serverFullName),
                       options);
scope.Connect();

ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery(
                        string.Format(@"SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name='{0}'",
                                      processToTerminate));
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);
ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
{
     m.InvokeMethod("Terminate", null);
}
```

1. is there another way of doing that ?
2. how can i start the process (if Terminate close it)?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

What about using the **ServiceController** class? (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ssbk2tf3.aspx))

```
// just replace the params with your values
ServiceController sc = new ServiceController("SERVICENAME", "MACHINENAME");
if (sc.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Running))
    sc.Stop();
```

This should do the trick.

hth

Answer (score 4):

It would seem a *lot* easier to just use the [`ServiceController`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7fs05y7h.aspx) class, that you can give a [service name and computer name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ssbk2tf3.aspx) to, and then call methods such as [`Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yb9w7ytd.aspx) and [`Stop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.stop.aspx).

Comment: I wanted to say the same thing; but I can't seem to find anything about specifying credentials for the remote system you want to connect to (As OP is doing with WMI). Or did I miss something?

Comment: @vcsjones - true, in their example, they do specify credentials. It's not clear whether that's a required part of the solution, or an artifact of the current code (e.g. if copied from elsewhere). It's not mentioned in the narrative, but I'm looking around to see if it's possible.

Comment: This is my problem, how can i give the remote computer its credentials ?

Comment: @guyl - [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3282927/manage-remote-service-using-alternate-credentials) seems to have a helper class written in VB.Net that establishes the credentials - looks reasonably easy to translate to C#. It's got some P/Invoke code, so pick your poison really - this or WMI.

Answer (score 3):

Killing a process and stoping a service are two different things. A service could spawn other processes that will remain lingering. Also, you are effectively pulling the plug on the process. It isn't being given any time to stop gracefully, write everything to disk, etc.

Instead you should use the [`Win32_Service`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI object to find your service. This has a `StartService` and `StopService` method, which will allow you to stop and start it as you need.

Mind you, this WMI object is about *services*, not processes, so you will have to tweak your code to stop it by the service name, not the process name. Something like this:

```
ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
options.Username = userName;
options.Password = password;

ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(string.Format(@"\\{0}\root\cimv2", serverFullName), options);
scope.Connect();

ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery(string.Format(@"SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE Name='{0}'",serviceToStop));
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
{
   m.InvokeMethod("StopService", null);
}
```

Then later on you can use `InvokeMethod` on StartService.

Answer (score 0):

you can do some like this to start and stop your sql server

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = "net start \"Sql Server (SQLEXPRESS)\"";
    process.Start();
```